Why are the ticks so fast in my netlogo model?
I can't figure out why the ticks in my netlogo model is so fast. Here's the code snipped for the to go function:
to go
  every 1[
    create-food feed-rate [
      set shape "circle"
      set color rgb 255 0 0
      set size 1
      setxy (random-float (max-x - min-x) + min-x) (random-float (max-y - min-y) + min-y)
    ]
    ask patches with [  (pxcor >= min-x) and (pxcor <= max-x) and
      (pycor >= min-y) and (pycor <= max-y)] [
      set pcolor palette:scale-gradient [[78 155 178] [102 126 44]] total-ammonia 0 60
    ]

    if total-ammonia >= 30 [
      if random 10 < 5 [
        let fish-list sort fish
        let fish-pop-size length fish-list - 1
        let random-fish item random fish-pop-size  fish-list
        ask random-fish [
          die
        ]
      ]
    ]

    if total-ammonia > 5 [
      set total-ammonia total-ammonia - clean-rate
    ]

  ]

  ask fish[
    if any? other food in-radius (size)[
      set food-eaten food-eaten + 1
    ]
    ask other food in-radius (size) [
      set food-consumed food-consumed + 1
      set total-ammonia total-ammonia + 1
      die
    ]
  ]
  move-fish
  tick
end

When I run the model, it shoots up to around 5k to 10k ticks a second.
I've tried making it so that it only ticks every 30 seconds, however this is not a solution I prefer. If I could get the ticks to slow down by a lot that'd be nice.

Ticks are incremented when you call tick. In your case, this is at the end of go and thus when all commands of your go have been executed. The speed at which ticks are incremented therefore depends on the computational complexity of your go procedure.
If you want to increase the time a go takes, you could use wait (see here). If you want to change the speed at which all your procedures are displayed, use the speed slider at the top of the NetLogo interface.
You find more information on this in the "View Updates" section of the Programming Guide.

Using for wait for this will prevent the speed slider from working. It's better to set the frame rate in the view settings, as per https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#frame-rate
